# Is it possible to teach Gmail to auto-hyperlink words in the body of an email?

Tags: gmail, links, automation

I'm finding that I often write emails where the same words or phrases need to be hyperlinked to the same site every time I type them.

I'm not talking about typing out *website names* that I want to be hyperlinked ("You should visit stackexchange.com because it's awesome!"), but rather, *actual words / phrases* ("It's an awesome [network of sites]", where "network of sites" is linked to stackexchange.com/sites).

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this? I'm envisioning something like autocorrect for spelling, something where I can teach the tool "Every time I type [x], link to [y]."

Is this even possible from a technical standpoint? I've looked to see if there's a Chrome extension or something in Google labs that will do this, but to no avail.

Comment: Sounds like you want something along the lines of http://www.smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/

Comment: The linkbuddy suggestion is the best. But if your "actual words/phrases" keep changing in every email, then you are basically looking for a text expander with support for placeholders. You could check out [these desktop apps](https://alternativeto.net/software/textexpander/), but some of them are paid/limited to only Mac/Windows. Not trying to self-advertise here, but the [ProKeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/prokeys/ekfnbpgmmeahnnlpjibofkobpdkifapn) chrome extension exactly supports placeholders (and much more). Good day!

Answer (score 3):

A very simple low-tech work-around is to maintain a file (e.g., Word, outlook task, etc.) with a list of these hyper-linked phrases and copy-paste the one you need into Gmail.

Another option that should work in most email clients like outlook is to define a simple signature for each such hyper-link.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. I know there are plenty of workarounds for this problem; was more wondering if someone had made some sleek, intuitive solution to it. :)